# HTML/JS Check for external async file generation

Tags: javascript, html, svg, promise, fs

I want to display svg that is generated by third party application in a HTML/js app. The problem I have is that the svg generation is async and when HTML tries to load svg, file may be missing (not written at the time) or incomplete (writing in progress). 
I looked at Promise but can't get any sample of checking an external file availability.
Any ideas ?

Comment: How are you (exactly) accessing the file so far?

Comment: I call external command from html. And once done, I update img src attribute through JQuery with external svg url. I need to set a time interval to ensure external file is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned in the comments, that you access the svg via an external url:

You can check with JavaScript/Jquery if an external file exists (as long as you can access via http)

Therefore you could do a check like that. If you find the file you update the image src and if not you retry it later:

Here is a little exmple implementation:

```
//example retry delay of 3 seconds
var delay = 3000;
var url = "http://www.doma.in/path/yourimg.svg";

function tryUpdate(){
    $.get(url)
        .done(function() { 
            //your picture exists
            updateImgSrc();
        }).fail(function() { 
            // picture doesn't exist yet -> retry after time
            setTimeout(tryUpdate, delay);
        })
}
```